# Prevent EditText from going to new line when 'Space' is tapped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to have an EditText which is multi Line and First Letter of a Sentence to be capital. I'm using:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:background="#ddebed"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/same" />
```

I can acheive both: MultiLine and CapSentences.
But, **When I press 'Space key' after a word, It goes to a new line.**
How do I prevent it?

The `android:text="@string/same"` refers to `<string name="same">\n \n \n Regards: Principal</string>`
So, The problem is being caused by **\n**'s.
 **I want to have an EditText which has some already typed text in next Line, And Allow User to enter some text in First 'n' lines.**

Comment: This code works as expected for me. You are not doing any changes from code to listen to text changes right??

Comment: I'm surely doing nothing with EditText in Java or anywhere else.

Comment: Chech the Updated Question Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **Add Two Hidden Spaces Before \n's.
To add a Hidden space: Alt + 0160 (Numpad  keys).**
So, When User is typing something, The Hidden Spaces will keep moving and UserText won't be able to reach to \n.

Answer (score 5):

Use `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:inputType="text"`

Your Edittext should look like below.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:background="#ddebed"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text|textCapSentences"
        android:text="@string/same" />
```

**OR**

If you are looking for multilines you can edit your edittext as

```
android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
```

Similarly you can increase `android:maxLines="2"`

I have checked it out. You can use above code with some below modifications.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
editText.setSelection(0);
```

It will move your cursor to position  0. Also try to increase maxlines value. I have checked it my end and it's working fine.

Comment: Tried it,Although It does not take me to new Line When Space is pressed.
But I want to keep it MultiLine , my Dear :)
Did you read the Question?

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can check it out Dear :)

Comment: Also it will be better if you mention the max length, so whenever it will reach at max length, it will take to next line. You can `android:maxLength="21"` attribute to your edittext.

Comment: I've found the Problem.
The `android:text="@string/same"` refers to `<string name="same">\n \n \n Regards: Principal</string>`

Comment: How Do I achive this,
Keping this text in next line?

Comment: Just one suggestion, if you want to add string "Regards : Principal" add the end, you can concatenate the edittext value and end string, or you want to show it add the end of edittext?

Comment: I had the idea of Concatenation,
But I want to keep it available for User to Change or Remove.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you please go through once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159628/discussion-between-androidonhigh-and-zubair-younas).

Comment: Hmm, You might be Correct, But I'm too lazy to do that (No Offense), 
Check my own posted Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tag in xml.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: I think it will stop going to multiline.

Comment: But I want to keep it MultiLine, Being not MultiLine on Space key.
Anyhow, It Didn't work :( Any other idea?