# Android: do not let EditText wrap by space

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml, word-wrap

If the length of the text in the EditText is too long, when add space in the text, the content after the space will be wrapped. For example, I have 60 1s without space or line break, and assume that each line can contain 20 1s, the EditText will show as below

```
11111111111111111111
11111111111111111111
11111111111111111111
```

But if I add space in it, it will be like this

```
11111111111111111111
1
11111111111111111111
1111111111111111111
```

I added space after the first 1 of the second line, and other 1 after that 1 was wrapped. What I expected is

```
11111111111111111111
1 111111111111111111
11111111111111111111
1
```

Is there any way to do it?

**edit:**

I'm trying to write a text editor, so I want   the EditText to be multiline.

My code is:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="start|top"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here? Maybe you can just limit your EditText to:

- being singleLine, `android:singleLine="true"`
- restricting user having few lines, `android:maxLines="1"`
- doing the trick with [line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447165/3874721)  `'\n'`

You should have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47446726/3874721). BTW provide more details on what are you trying to achieve in terms of user experience and representation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. How about:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:singleLine="false"
```